# Receive a string from an activity to one class file that extends view

Tags: android

I wanted to get a string from an Activity to a class file that 'extends view'. How can I receive the string. Can I use intents for that.

Comment: Didn't get your question, what are you trying to do with the file that extends view? what is the objective here?

Comment: You can use the Intents to send the data from the Activity to Activity  od services .

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have some OOD/OOP misunderstanding but there is a simplest way to do it:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static String sMyString = "Hello";
}

public class MyView extends View {
    public MyView() {
        String s = MainAcivity.sMyString;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to make static variables and Intents, You can pass a String as you pass and set other Variables.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle b){
        //....setContentView() blah blha blah
        // here you get View as new View or findViewById()

        MyView v = new MyView(this); //or (MyView)findViewById(R.id.id_in_layout);
        v.setString("Hi, this is a simple way..");
    }
}
```

How do you get `String` in your `View` class.

```
public class MyView extends View {
    private String mString;
    public void setString(String m)
    {
        mString = m;
    }
}
```

Here `mString` is class level, you can use it anywhere, inside any method after setting the `String`.